# Response.Redirect omitting Http Status 302

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, response.redirect, http-status-code-302

for 404 redirection, I was using the following code :

```
        try
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url, true);
        }
        catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
        { }
```

The problem with this redirection was that the page was being redirected to 404 page and there on the 
404 Page Code behind, I set the Http Status to 404. So, when a non existing url is given in the browser, first a Http Status 302 and then a Http Status 400 was received.

The requirement is to omit this Http Status 302. I tried a few alternatives and then I implemented it like the following :

```
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url, false);
            if (url.Contains("404.aspx"))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            }
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Now, the error page redirection and the Http status code 404 are correct, but in the browser url string, the faulty url remains. I was expecting to have the url {hostname}/404.aspx but instead I am still seeing the faulty url in the browser but the 404.aspx is displayed. So, it acts like a Server.Redirect.

Is that the expected behaviour? How can I force the browser to display 404.aspx on the URL String but still return only Http Status 404 without an Http Status 302 before?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I think you are already correct.  The user made a request for `http://site/MissingPage.aspx`, your server could not find the page and returns status 404 with customised HTML error message.  Their browser should still show `http://site/MissingPage.aspx`, otherwise how will they know what the bad url was?  Also they can easily correct any typo now.

You can see how other sites have implemented custom 404 pages:

- https://stackoverflow.com/thisisnotapage
- http://www.google.com/thisisnotapage
- https://github.com/thisisnotapage